# Find $x+ \frac {2}{1 .3} x^3 + \frac {2.4}{1.3.5} x^5 + \dots \infty $ for all $x \in (0, 1)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find the closed form of $$x+ \frac {2}{1\cdot 3} x^3 + \frac {2\cdot 4}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5} x^5 + \dots \quad \forall x \in (0, 1)$$

**My approach:**

Clearly we can see the formation of factorial in the denominator. so the series becomes-

$$x+ \frac {2^2}{3!} x^3 + \frac {2^2\cdot 4^2}{5!} x^5 + \dots $$

I cannot remember a series like that. then the other approach left is integration. now what to integrate, I am confused about that. I am just a beginner in this.

Comment: what do you mean by "find"?

Comment: I think he means closed form expression

Comment: I mean to converge it to a specific trigonometric form.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091153/closed-form-expression-for-infinite-series/3091193#3091193